# Innovations in deformation theory

Tags: ho.history-overview, deformation-theory

I've been trying to get into deformation theory lately, and I became thirsty for a bit of context.

Has Deformation Theory seen a lot of development since its inception? If I read Michael Artin's "Deformations of Singularities" - would that be representative of the understanding today?

To put it more pointedly: What is the outline of the evolution of deformation theory?

Comment: Here you go: http://www.math.columbia.edu/~doran/Hist%20Ann%20Bib.pdf

Comment: For more modern developments, see Kontsevich-Soibelman's book on deformation theory and Jacob Lurie's ICM talk.

Comment: It's a nice question. What was there pre-Kodaira-Spencer? There was quite a bit in geometry, I believe. What exactly is said in SGA1 (this is opaque to me, but I have wanted to know for a long time)?

Comment: have you noticed the first link has only the odd numbered pages?

Comment: oh, probably my screen was too narrow.

Comment: @Kevin Lin: The first link seems to no longer work. Any thoughts? (I tried looking at the authors website and it doesn't seem to be publicly posted there)